# Android LibVLC : video Surface

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, libvlc

How can I set the Surface to display the Video in a Java-Android App?

Currently I do:

```
        mSurfaceHolder = GUIconfig.videoWindow.getHolder();
        mLibVLC = LibVLC.getInstance();
        mLibVLC.init(GUIconfig.mainWindow);
        mLibVLC.useIOMX();

        mLibVLC.attachSurface(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface(), new IVideoPlayer() {

            @Override
            public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height, int visible_width,
                    int visible_height, int sar_num, int sar_den) {

            }
        }, GUIconfig.screenWidth, GUIconfig.screenHeight);
        mLibVLC.readMedia("rtsp://129.69.207.174:8554/Stream", false);
        mLibVLC.play();
```

GUIconfig.videoWindow is a SurfaceView

The LogCat displays warnings: yuv_rgb_neon filter: can't get output picture

It plays sound, but I cannot see a video. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
LibVLC libVLC = new LibVLC();
MediaPlayer  mMediaPlayer =  new org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer(libVLC);
VlcVout mVlcVout = mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
mVlcVout.setVideoView({**YOUR TEXTUREVIEW**});
mVlcVout.attachViews();
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

You may find the correct way to use LibVLC inside an Activity by reading the [video activity code from vlc-android](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc-ports/android.git;a=blob;f=vlc-android/src/org/videolan/vlc/gui/video/VideoPlayerActivity.java;h=3fa59bde1108d3ce606aa98bea767ed5bfb41026;hb=HEAD)

hth

Answer (score 0):

See this question [Integrating videolan in Android for live streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966870/integrating-videolan-in-android-for-live-streaming)

you need

```
mLibVLC.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);
mLibVLC.eventVideoPlayerActivityCreated(true);
```

Comment: LibVLC class doesn't have such methods