# Integrating videolan in Android for live streaming

Tags: android

I have integrated videolan in my android app. I followed the steps in the videolan wiki page to compile the vlc source.

I am streaming live content and I can hear the audio but no video. I've been trying to find a solution online/videolan forums but no luck. any help will be very much appreciated.

I overwrote the `setSurfaceSize` method and I still don't see the video. I can only hear the audio and I see this in the logs.

```
005-30 23:37:33.085: W/VLC(5099): yuv_rgb_neon filter: can't get output picture
05-30 23:37:33.190: W/VLC(5099): yuv_rgb_neon filter: can't get output picture
05-30 23:37:33.190: W/VLC(5099): core video output: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 31 ms)
05-30 23:37:33.195: W/VLC(5099): yuv_rgb_neon filter: can't get output picture
05-30 23:37:33.300: W/VLC(5099): yuv_rgb_neon filter: can't get output picture
05-30 23:37:33.300: W/VLC(5099): core video output: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 41 ms)
05-30 23:37:33.300: D/VLC(5099): core video output: picture might be displayed late (missing 8 ms)
05-30 23:37:33.305: W/VLC(5099): yuv_rgb_neon filter: can't get output picture
05-30 23:37:33.310: W/VLC(5099): yuv_rgb_neon filter: can't get output picture
05-30 23:37:33.415: W/VLC(5099): yuv_rgb_neon filter: can't get output picture
05-30 23:37:33.420: W/VLC(5099): core video output: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 24 ms)
```

Comment: I got it to work. I had to set these two fields.  mLibVLC.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);
mLibVLC.eventVideoPlayerActivityCreated(true);